# PHP date() not returning expected value

Tags: php

This is strange.  Either I am losing my mind or this is really simple and I am just overlooking something obvious.

I have a script that is run automatically daily (around 9:00am central time) by a cron job that I tried to set up to "take a vacation" on January 1.  It seemed like the easy solution was to add the following line at the top of my script:

```
if( date("n/j")=='1/1' ){ exit(); }
```

Yet somehow it did not exit, but rather ran anyway.  Not really a big deal...but I hope to fix it for next year.  I tried today in a sample script using the following and it identified the date correctly and exited without running the rest of the code...

```
if( date("n/j")=='1/3' ){ exit('January 3'); }
```

...so I am perplexed.  Is January 1 not represented as 1/1?

Comment: Uh, Try `date("n/j", time())`

Comment: @user1909426: it is the same as date("n/j")

Comment: @user1909426 this is default for date.

Comment: I tested it, and it works fine. Is there any other code that might be at fault?

Comment: Right.. I just thought maybe in this context, it may be working differently

Comment: Seems to run fine. http://codepad.org/zxtPOCoz

Comment: Is your webserver perhaps in another timezone? Did it skip thew 31st or the 2nd?

Comment: Is timezone properly set on server?

Comment: What time did the cron fire? Maybe it was close enough to midnight that it was the 2nd when PHP hit this line. (D'oh nevermind, just saw that time notation in the OP.)

Comment: Your code is correct. There is another problem somewhere. Are you absolutely certain it ran on 1/1?

Comment: I am certain it ran on 1/1 because it's job is to send out any emails that are sitting in a queue on my server (long story...)  I have emails dated 1/1, so i know it ran.  I used this same code logic however on Christmas day and DID NOT get any emails (thus, it worked correctly).  Very strange.  I doubt it is a timezone issue.  I am on a shared hosting platform (with 1and1) and the server time is Eastern (New York).  I am in Central (Chicago)...and it runs at 9am.

Answer (score 0):

There is no logical reason why it should not work. It works

```
<?php
if( date("n/j",strtotime("1/1/2013"))=='1/1') 
{
   echo "it does match";
   exit();
}
?>
```

Did it run on 12/31 or 1/2 ? Could happen due to timezone differnce like other people are suggesting to check

Comment: I am certain it ran on 1/1 because it's job is to send out any emails that are sitting in a queue on my server (long story...) I have emails dated 1/1, so i know it ran. I used this same code logic however on Christmas day and DID NOT get any emails (thus, it worked correctly). Very strange. I doubt it is a timezone issue. I am on a shared hosting platform (with 1and1) and the server time is Eastern (New York). I am in Central (Chicago)...and it runs at 9am.